# How to parse JSON file into Python list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to parse a JSON file into Python but failing to print any specific data I am trying to pull from JSON.

How can I put these JSON data in separate arrays, so I can play with them in Python?

This is the JSON file:

```
{
"Ask":
   {"0":[[9.13,30200],[9.14,106946],[9.15,53072],[9.16,58104],[9.17,45589]],
    "1":[[9.14,106946],[9.15,53072],[9.16,58104],[9.17,45589],[9.18,37521]] },

"Bid":
   {"0":[[9.12,198807],[9.11,1110],[9.1,42110],[9.09,84381],[9.08,98178]],
    "1":[[9.13,13500],[9.12,198807],[9.11,1110],[9.1,42110],[9.09,84381]]}
}
```

and this is my code:

```
import json

with open("JSON Directory") as BOB:
    data=json.load(BOB)

for x in data["Bid"]:
    print(x["0"])
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: I did that sorry, I didnt post it, there is no problem with reading the file

Comment: @YashPokar `'r'` is the default mode for opening files.

Comment: I have made Python read the JSON succesfully, there is no problem with reading the file. Problem is I cant get the values for Bid "0"

Comment: `data['Bid']` gives you a dictionary. Your need to look up how to iterate through a dictionary.

Comment: adding "print x" to the line before your error should clear up your understanding. When you iterate over a dictionary, you get the key, not the value.

Comment: @JanisGustavian replace `print(x["0"])` by `print(data["Bid"][x])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's just a slight problem with your for loop.

```
james@VIII:~/Desktop$ ls
f.txt
james@VIII:~/Desktop$ cat f.txt 
{
"Ask":
   {"0":[[9.13,30200],[9.14,106946],[9.15,53072],[9.16,58104],[9.17,45589]],
    "1":[[9.14,106946],[9.15,53072],[9.16,58104],[9.17,45589],[9.18,37521]] },

"Bid":
   {"0":[[9.12,198807],[9.11,1110],[9.1,42110],[9.09,84381],[9.08,98178]],
    "1":[[9.13,13500],[9.12,198807],[9.11,1110],[9.1,42110],[9.09,84381]]}
}
james@VIII:~/Desktop$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> with open('f.txt') as f_in:
...     data = json.load(f_in)
... 
>>> data
{'Ask': {'0': [[9.13, 30200], [9.14, 106946], [9.15, 53072], [9.16, 58104], [9.17, 45589]], '1': [[9.14, 106946], [9.15, 53072], [9.16, 58104], [9.17, 45589], [9.18, 37521]]}, 'Bid': {'0': [[9.12, 198807], [9.11, 1110], [9.1, 42110], [9.09, 84381], [9.08, 98178]], '1': [[9.13, 13500], [9.12, 198807], [9.11, 1110], [9.1, 42110], [9.09, 84381]]}}
>>> data['Ask']
{'0': [[9.13, 30200], [9.14, 106946], [9.15, 53072], [9.16, 58104], [9.17, 45589]], '1': [[9.14, 106946], [9.15, 53072], [9.16, 58104], [9.17, 45589], [9.18, 37521]]}
>>> 
>>> data['Bid']
{'0': [[9.12, 198807], [9.11, 1110], [9.1, 42110], [9.09, 84381], [9.08, 98178]], '1': [[9.13, 13500], [9.12, 198807], [9.11, 1110], [9.1, 42110], [9.09, 84381]]}
>>> for x in data['Bid']['0']:
...     print(x)
... 
[9.12, 198807]
[9.11, 1110]
[9.1, 42110]
[9.09, 84381]
[9.08, 98178]
```

Your for loop just needed to be changed a little.

PS you don't need to specify 'r' when reading the file.

You can also get individual values like this:

```
>>> for x in data['Bid']['0']:
...     print(str(x[0]) + ': ' + str(x[1]))
... 
9.12: 198807
9.11: 1110
9.1: 42110
9.09: 84381
9.08: 98178
```

Comment: How can I get just 9.12 for example ? I am trying to write a generalized code to get for example

i:1to10

['Bid']['0'][i]-['Ask']['0'][i]

Comment: It looks ugly but here you go hahaha:  
data['Bid']['0'][0][0]   (prints 9.12)

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- Convert **Before**

  ```
  for x in data["Bid"]:
    print(x["0"])
  ```
- Into **After**

  ```
  for x in data["Bid"]:
    print(data["Bid"][x])
  ```

### Problem

- Python data reference to loaded JSON data is not producing the desired result

### Solution

- Correctly identify the JSON address as either a dictionary key or a string
- In the original example `print(x["0"])` is an incorrect reference because `x` is a string (dictionary key)
- This can be verified by using using python `pprint.pprint()` to troubleshoot what you are looking for

### Example

```
## import pprint 
## we use this to inspect the data to make sure we are
## working with what we expect

import pprint
pass

# [...] (loading code omitted)

for x in data["Bid"]:
  pprint.pprint(x)
# u'1'
# u'0'
```

### Example Modified

```
## pprint the values

for x in data.values():
  pprint.pprint(x)

# {u'0': [[9.13, 30200],
#         [9.14, 106946],
#         [9.15, 53072],
#         [9.16, 58104],
#         [9.17, 45589]],
#  u'1': [[9.14, 106946],
#         [9.15, 53072],
#         [9.16, 58104],
#         [9.17, 45589],
#         [9.18, 37521]]}
# {u'0': [[9.12, 198807],
#         [9.11, 1110],
#         [9.1, 42110],
#         [9.09, 84381],
#         [9.08, 98178]],
#  u'1': [[9.13, 13500],
#         [9.12, 198807],
#         [9.11, 1110],
#         [9.1, 42110],
#         [9.09, 84381]]}
```

### Example Corrected

```
## we are looking at dictionary keys with `x`
## if we want to iterate the dictionary keys in data["Bid"]
## we need to correctly reference what we are looking for

for x in data["Bid"]:
  print(data["Bid"][x])

# [[9.13, 13500], [9.12, 198807], [9.11, 1110], [9.1, 42110], [9.09, 84381]]
# [[9.12, 198807], [9.11, 1110], [9.1, 42110], [9.09, 84381], [9.08, 98178]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The value `data["Bid"]` is a dict, and by iterating over a dict with:

```
for x in data["Bid"]:
```

you are actually iterating over the keys of the dict, which are strings and cannot be indexed with a non-integer like `x["0"]`.

If you intend to iterate over the sub-lists under the `0` key of the `data["Bid"]` dict, you should instead do:

```
for x in data["Bid"]['0']:
    print(x)
```

Comment: `strings and cannot be indexed with an integer like x["0"]` in python, strings actually *can* be indexed with an integer. For example, `x[0]` would return a result instead of an error (not the expected result though, but that is a separate issue).

Comment: Oops that was a typo indeed. Fixed then.

Comment: Great ! Thank you. Can you show me an `for `example to store these Bid `0`  values in an array

Comment: @JanisGustavian You don't need a `for` loop to store the `data["Bid"]['0']` list because it is already a list. Just assign it to a variable directly: `lst = data["Bid"]['0']`

Comment: I got you, thank you for your insightful comment. 

I am trying to make some calculations such as

i : 1 to 10

data["Bid"]['i'] First Index -data["Ask"]['i'] First Index

Comment: @JanisGustavian Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Comment: Sure, done. Sorry if Im asking too much, Im trying to make calculations such as

 i : 1 to 10 

data["Bid"]['i'] First Index -data["Ask"]['i'] First Index

data["Bid"]['i'] Second Index -data["Ask"]['i'] Second Index

Answer (score 0):

your for is loop in the keys of dict.

```
for x in data["Bid"]:
  print(type(x))
# <class 'str'>
```

try it:

```
for x in data['Bid']['0']:
 print(x)
```

or

```
for x in data['Bid'].values():
 print(x)
```

sorry for my English :)